# Support of create, update and delete endpoint for repeating invoice in Xero API

Tags: xero-api

I just released that Xero API do not support create, update and delete for repeating invoice. They seems to only support read...

In my company, we are building a CRM website and having the ability to manage repeating invoice would be a GREAT help. This feature is a core feature for us and it would save us a lot of time and man power.

Someone knows if this feature would come someday or if you have a workaround?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve (GET) repeating invoices via the Xero API, but creating and updating (PUT/POST) are not currently supported.

Upvote the [feature suggestion](https://xero.uservoice.com/forums/5528-xero-api/suggestions/2257421-create-a-repeating-invoice-via-the-api) to show your support.